# Wait for GET request completed

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to figure out how can I tell the application to wait until one task going to finish. I need to do two rest request and they depends of each other. The second one need data from first one to be successfully.

So the way I am doing my test request is :

```
func get(completion: @escaping (Any?) -> Void){
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: ["token": TOKEN]).validate().responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.value != nil {
                // DESERIALIZE IT INTO ARRAY " objects"
                }
                completion(objects)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

and the second get which needs the data from first looking simmilar like this one - only the change is the URL.

Then I would like to invoke both functions somewhere in my application and do smth with deserialized data.

```
func loadData() {
        Service.Instance.get{ (json) in
            guard json != nil else {
                print("Error / json = nil pointer")
                return
            }
            self.data = json as! [Data]
        }

        for dt in self.data {
            Service.Instance.get(data: dt, offset: 0, limit: 10, completion: { (json2) in
                guard json2 != nil else {
                    print("Error / json = nil pointer")
                    return
                }
                if dt.count > 0 {
                    self.objects = json2 as! [VehicleModel]!
                    self.fulldata.append(self.objects)
                } else {
                    print("There is no object in the Array")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

So I would like to tell the application to wait for first request finished before starts next cuz it will crash with `nil` in for loop.

Comment: `for dt in self.data {` put that just after `self.data = json as! [Data]`, inside the first `Service.Instance.get` closure.

Comment: @Larme right! What about refreshing table view ? If I invoke `loadData()` and then `self.tableView.` It's not going to wait for finish `loadData()` function ;c

Comment: Do it just after `self.fulldata.append(self.objects)` ?

Comment: @Larme Yes. I did it. Thanks for your help!